# How does the Social Media Report work in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I'm relying on the Social Media Report (under Acquisition -> Social) to see the conversion ratio from the social media traffic. However im not sure what GA consider social media traffic.

So for example if the user

1. saw a post about my new article on twitter,
2. and clicks on the link from twitter to my blog post
3. he reads the article then navigates to a Request Demo page and fill the contact form,

Assuming that im setting the goal for the form submission, will GA consider this a Social Media traffic, considering there was an intermediate step which is the actual blog post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for your example, yes, GA would consider this a conversion through social media.
Analytics looks at the source which initially brought the visitor to your site (in this case Twitter), and this will stay the source and be accredited with the conversion, regardless of how many pages they then visit (as long as they stay on your site).

Analytics works with the last-click attribution model, so if the path your user takes is indeed this straightforward (clicks on Twitter link > reads blog post > sends enquiry), the last source, i.e. the last click through which the visitor landed on your site, will be attributed with the conversion.

If a user takes a more complex path, it gets a little trickier. E.g. user clicks on Twitter link > read blog post > bookmarks your site > comes back later that day and finishes reading the post > comes back a few days later > sends enquiry. In this case, the last click through which this user came to your site before converting would be 'direct' not 'social', as they came through their bookmark.

Google knows that conversion paths aren't always straightforward, so as a starting point, have a look into "Multi-Channel Funnels > Top Conversion Paths and doodle around in there to see which channels were involved in a conversion.

Comment: great thanks, but this is Assisted Conversion in your example right, I read somewhere that this is the difference between assisted and direct conversion